# Changing Cursor cause an Exception

Tags: android, cursor, textwatcher

I have a ListView in a dialog and an EditText to filter my list for CustomerCodes,i've implemented my filter query with a TextWatcher and in onTextChanged() i've changed my old Cursor with

```
Cursor FilteredCPCodeList = CustomerDBAdapter.instance.CursorFilteredCPCode(s.toString());  //Retrieve Filtered CustomerCodeList
CpListadapter.changeCursor(FilteredCPCodeList);
```

List Filtering works Perfect with codes above but when i click on a ListItem it's OnItemClickListener which use old Cursor cause an Exception which tells :

```
01-05 10:33:01.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5380): android.database.StaleDataException: Attempting to access a closed CursorWindow.Most probable cause: cursor is deactivated prior to calling this method.
```

i know that change cursor will close my old cursor but i don't know how can i use StopManagingCursor on my old cursor(or another soloution) to solve this Issue.i've tried this code on onTextChanged() but it doesn't work either

```
Cursor OldCursor = CpListadapter.getCursor();
stopManagingCursor(OldCursor );
```

any help would be appreciated,Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stopManagingCursor()` is deprecated and not recommended anymore. You should be using [`CursorLoader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html). Then you can use a `SimpleCursorAdapter` along with the `swapCursor(Cursor)` method.

If you need to use your current setup, you should be able to do `CpListadapter.getCursor().close()` (for example, in your `onDestroy()`).

Comment: Thank you oleg replacing change cursor with swapcursor solved my problem.

Comment: Yeah, unlike `changeCursor()`, `swapCursor()` does not close the original. Just note that it requires API 11 unless you use `android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter` from the compatibility library.